rational functions flat over $k[x]$
I was looking at the solution of an exercise, which proved the following statement:

The $k[x]$-module $k(x)$ of rational functions for $k$ a field is flat.

The solution goes as follows:
Let $\phi: N \rightarrow N'$ be an injection of modules and consider an element in the kernel of $\phi : N \otimes k(x) \rightarrow N' \otimes k(x)$. We have:
$$ \phi( \sum_i n_i \otimes \frac{p_i}{q_i}) = 0$$
for some $p_i,q_i \in k(x) \setminus \{ 0\}$ and $n_i \in N$. Wlog we can factor out the $q_i$ such that $\sum_i n_i \otimes \frac{p_i}{q_i} = \sum_i n_i \otimes \frac{p_i}{q}$ and since $q$ acts invertibly we can multiply by $q$ and obtain:
$$ \sum_i \phi(p_in_i) \otimes 1 = 0 = \phi(\sum_i p_in_i) \otimes 1$$
Up until that point I agree. However, it seems to me that we can conclude from here:

By assumption, $\phi$ is injective and thus $\ker(\phi : N \rightarrow N') = \{ 0\} \implies \sum_i p_in_i = 0$ and we are done.

The solution however uses a much more complicated argument,which I don't understand the need for:

We prove that $\phi(\sum_i p_in_i) \otimes 1 = 0 \implies \sum_i n_i p_i = 0$ as follows: There is $n \in N$ such that $n = \sum_i n_i p_i$ and now consider the map $\psi: k[x] \rightarrow N, 1 \mapsto n$: Is it is injective and thus $\phi \circ \psi$ induces an isomorphism $k[x] \simeq \langle\phi(n) \rangle \subset N'$ and hence $k(x) \simeq \langle\phi(n) \rangle \otimes k(x)$ via $1 \mapsto \phi(n)$ which is impossible since $\phi(n) \otimes 1 = 0$ by assumption. Thus, pick any  nontrivial element $f$ in the kernel of $\psi$, then:
$$n \otimes f = n \otimes \frac{f}{f} = nf \otimes \frac{1}{f} = 0 \otimes \frac{1}{f} = 0$$

Why do we need this step?

You should be treating $k(x)$ as a $k[x]$-module in this context. It's not rigorous to "factor out the $1/q$," since that's treating $k(x)$ as if it's the base ring.

Thank you. This was mostly a typing error. We cannot take out the $1/q$, however by mutliplyting by $q$ we recover the  $ (- \otimes 1)$

$a\otimes1$ doesn't imply $a=0$, so you don't know that $\phi(\sum p_in_i)=0$.

But we know $\varphi(a\otimes 1) = 0 = \varphi(a)\otimes 1$ which

You should show that for any commutative, unital ring $A$ and and any multiplicatevily closed subset $S$ tensoring with $S^{-1}A$ coincides with taking the modules of fractions. The latter operation is exact and so  $S^{-}A$ is flat
